# How to make a child elements shadow show above parent that has overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

I need to have shadows in the `img` element, but since it's wraped in a div that's got `overflow: hidden`, the shadows are hidden as well. What could I adjust here to make the shadows appear?

```
.slider-content .slider-image{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*width: 20%;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 120;
    max-width: 218px;
    max-height: 135px;
    margin-right: 1.7%;
}
.slider-content .slider-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #222;
}
```

The markup is as follows:

```
<div clss="slider-content">
  <div class="slider-image">
    <img src=".." />
  </div>
  <div class="slider-image">
    <img src=".." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add padding to the outer to match the shadow size

Answer (score 2):

Since you `img` will always fill the `.slider-image`, put the shadow on the `.slider-image` element.

```
.slider-content .slider-image{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*width: 20%;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 120;
    max-width: 218px;
    max-height: 135px;
    margin-right: 1.7%;

    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #222;
}
.slider-content .slider-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: There's a catch - that's also within a wrapper that has the same `overflow:hidden` property :)

Comment: @Xeen: then place the shadow on that element then?

Comment: @jbutler483 no can do, `.slider-content` is also `135px` in height, but `100%` in width.

Comment: as @jbutler483 mentioned if they have the same dimensions you will have to add it to the parent. The point is that `overflow:hidden` cuts off everything from its descendants (*no way around it*).

Comment: a small trick is to add some *air* inside the container in order to allow for the shadows of the children..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: Padding-top?

Comment: @jbutler483 that could work (*it really depends on the overall setup*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I did as you suggested and added some margins to the image within the `.slider-image`, now it works, but I guess it's a somewhat dirty solution because the size of the `img` had to be compromised.

Comment: @xeen, you could extend the `.slider-content` element (*and add some negative margins to make it stay where it is*) and keep the images intact (*in terms of size*). If you had a live demo it would be easier to suggest workarounds..